# The word for "motivated by future reward (income)"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Do we have a word for describing someone (or something) as "motivated by future rewards or incomes" instead of "immediate rewards"?

The usage of the word is in the documentation of a concept, in which an algorithm is used to decide about the state of a system and is more interested in the rewards that are coming later instead of immediate effects of the decision.

Not necessarily searching for a word to describe the entire concept, however, it would be great to have the minimum number of characters to describe the idea as it is going to be used in a paper as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not perfect for the context you describe but how about 'deferred gratification'?

Comment: The more common one is "delayed gratification", both are synonymous though.

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is correct by itself, may I suggest the somewhat more common *delayed gratification* instead?